# How many inactive wallets are dormant with NFTs in them?

Tags: wallets, nft

I have been thinking of "rarity" a little differently from NFT pricing perspective, and I'm trying to draw a correlation to NFT rarity and dead wallets. Is there anywhere that I can actively get this information without diving into each individual wallet? Thoughts on this?

Comment: It isn't a very common statistic. I'd start from TheGraph or BigQuery.